# Which multivariate Gaussian has the highest expected norm?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional Gaussian vector with zero mean and covariance matrix $K$ given by:

$$K_{ij} = \begin{cases} p_i(1-p_i) & i=j \\ -p_ip_j & i\neq j\end{cases}~,$$

where $(p_i)_{i=1}^n$ is a probability vector, i.e. $p_i\geq 0,\ \forall\  i,$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1.$ Such Gaussian vectors naturally arise from the multinomial distribution.

For any vector $x,$ and for any $p\geq 1,$ let $||x||_p:=\left(\sum_i |x_i|^p\right)^{\frac 1p}$ denote the $p$-norm of the vector.

> Conjecture:
>   Among all probability vectors, the uniform probability vector $p_i = \frac{1}{n}$ maximizes the expected $p$-norm of $X,$ namely the quantity
>   $$\mathbb{E}\left[\|X\|_p\right]$$

Note: If instead, we wished to maximize $\mathbb{E}\left[\|X\|_p^p\right],$ then it is easy to show the uniform probability vector is the best choice since $\|X\|_p^p$ neatly decomposes into a sum. This also means that the conjecture is true for $p=1.$

Comment: I suspect that my conjecture above is incorrect. This is not a fully rigorous argument, but I believe it should be possible to make it so. Let $s\to\infty,$ so we are dealing with $||x||_\infty = \max_i |x_i|.$ Then, the value of the expected norm for the uniform distribution will be $\sim \sqrt{\frac{2\log n}{n}}$ (the entries are not independent, but almost nearly so for large $n$), however if one chooses the distribution that makes $p_1 = \frac 12,$ and $p_i$ equal for all the rest, then the expected norm is $\Omega(1).$